# mdi child doesn't show maximized

Tags: windows, winforms, mdi, mdichild

We're having the following issue in our application: When we open an mdi childform it comes in maximize windowstate as it should be but it is shown in normal state.Tthe background from the parent is still visible on the right and bottom side.

However when i change the childform to normal state and maximize it again it is shown as maximized. But when the application is closed and restarted the form comes again with the issue.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Is this a problem related to windows? or something else?

```
Private Sub tbrMngr_ToolClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.ToolClickEventArgs) Handles tbrMngrCeres.ToolClick

    Try

        '--> Handle click '
        If Not e.Tool.SharedProps.Tag Is Nothing Then

            Select Case CType(e.Tool.SharedProps.Tag, String).ToUpper
                Case "M_MANAGEMENT" : HandleManagementClick(e.Tool.Key)
            End Select

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
```

here is the case selected from what button  on th menubar has been clicked. All the problems only come within HandleManagementClick

```
 Private Sub HandleManagementClick(ByVal pstrKey As String)

    Try

        Dim lblnNonModal As Boolean = True

        If Not Me.ifrmActiveForm Is Nothing Then
            If Not ifrmActiveForm.Disposing Then
                ifrmActiveForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
                ifrmActiveForm.Dispose()
                ifrmActiveForm = Nothing
                iNotifiers = Nothing
            End If
        End If

        Me.Cursor = Cursors.AppStarting

        Select Case pstrKey.ToUpper
            Case "RES" : Me.ifrmActiveForm = New frmReservationWizard(Me.iclsApp, "RES")
            Case "RCAT" : Me.ifrmActiveForm = New frmFacilityCategory(Me.iclsApp, "RCAT")
            Case "RGRP" : Me.ifrmActiveForm = New frmFacilityGroup(Me.iclsApp, "RGRP")

        End Select

        If Not ifrmActiveForm Is Nothing Then
            If pstrKey.ToUpper.Equals("RES") Then
                'ifrmActiveForm.ShowInTaskbar = False
                ifrmActiveForm.ShowDialog()
                ' Me.ShowScreen(FormWindowState.Normal, False, lblnNonModal, FormStartPosition.CenterScreen)
                ifrmActiveForm.Dispose()
            Else
                Me.ShowScreen(FormWindowState.Maximized, False, lblnNonModal, FormStartPosition.CenterScreen)

            End If
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
```

As you see the windowstate property is set on maximize at the showscreen sub.

```
 Private Function ShowScreen(ByVal pWindowState As FormWindowState, _
                            ByVal pblnRegisterChild As Boolean, _
                            ByVal pblnIsMdiChild As Boolean, _
                            ByVal pStartPosition As FormStartPosition) As DialogResult

    Dim lDialResult As DialogResult = DialogResult.None
    Dim lblnOpeningScreen As Boolean

    Try

        If Not lblnOpeningScreen Then

            lblnOpeningScreen = True

            Me.iNotifiers = Nothing

            If pblnIsMdiChild Then

                If pblnRegisterChild Then RegisterChild(AddressOf ifrmActiveForm.ParentNotifier)

                ifrmActiveForm.WindowState = pWindowState
                ifrmActiveForm.MdiParent = Me
                ifrmActiveForm.Show()

            Else
                lDialResult = ifrmActiveForm.ShowDialog()
            End If

        End If

        Return lDialResult

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
```

I hope this covers a bit more documentation.

Kind Regards,

Kristof

Comment: Don't create child forms until the MDI parent's Load event has fired.  That's the earliest point in time that its true size is known.

Comment: The parent's Load event loads the first child at start up perfect. But for the next forms we open by selecting it with a menu-item it comes out with the issue.

Comment: You will need to document your problem better.  At a minimum a code snippet, a small repro project that demonstrates this issue and available on a file sharing service is best.

Comment: I hope this update covers more information how the forms are handled.

Comment: You are showing a dialog, not an MDI child window.

Comment: the code never comes into the part of showdialog except for 1 form. So pblnIsMdiChild is always on true wich makes it comes into ifrmActiFrom.Show